# Error: "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-appbar

I'm trying to show a toast message when clicking on a toolbar action, but I got this error

> @composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @composable function

Code:

```
@Composable
fun Toolbar() {
    TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "Jetpack Compose") }, navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = {}) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu)
        }
    }, actions = {
        IconButton(onClick = {
            showMessage(message = "test")
        }) {
            Icon(vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_save_24))
        }
    })
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun ToolbarPreview(){
    Toolbar()
}

@Composable
fun showMessage(message:String){
    Toast.makeText(ContextAmbient.current, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `onClick` parameter doesn't accept a composable function.
Remove the `@Composable` annotation in the `showMessage`.
Use something like:

```
@Composable
fun Toolbar() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    TopAppBar(title = {},
            actions = {
        IconButton(onClick = {
            showMessage(context, message = "test")
        }){}
    })
}

fun showMessage(context: Context, message:String){
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do this though? this is basic UI behaviour in any other framework? How does on display a view or change a veiw state from an onClick() event?

Comment: Good point, unfortunately, I am still having the issue when calling show message from a LazyColumn nested in a Box. Is it because of the tree-nature of compose?

Comment: @user901790: Your UI should be composed based on state data, meaning the UI is never modified directly. Instead, to "modify" the UI you modify the state which in turn causes the UI to recompose and visually change.

Comment: Btw. `ContextAmbient` is now called `LocalContext`

Comment: @m.reiter thanks for feedback. Answer updated.

Comment: How to show a AlertDialog Instead?

Comment: @WalterBerggren Thanks, that was a helpful comment. Use onClick to change the compose state & the UI will be changed reactively. That is the way to go in jetpack compose. It's different from the usual javascript click listeners.

Answer (score 18):

I got the same error and my solution was adding a `@Composable` annotation to the parameter in my method where I pass another composable function.

Example:

```
fun drawScreen(navigationIcon: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    navigationIcon()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone wants to use Composable on click event

```
Column {
    var isClicked by mutableStateOf(false)

    Button(onClick = { isClicked = true }) { Text(text = "Click Me") }

    if (isClicked) {
        isClicked = false
        // display your composable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
@Composable
fun MyTopAppBar(
        title: String,
        actionItem: TopBarActionItem,
        navigationClick: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null) {}
```

And how do you invoke navigationClick?
The `invoke()` method itself is not composable and got the error again.

You can't use `navigationClick?.invoke()`

Answer (score 1):

Here onClick() doesn't need any Composable function that's why it is throwing an error.
Just remove **@Composable** from the `showMessage` function.

Comment: Then he cannot use LocalContext.current (because it is @composable)