# @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

There is a similar question [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801346/composable-invocations-can-only-happen-from-the-context-of-an-composable-funct).
But it doesn't solve my problem.

I get this error "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @composable function" after building my project, even though the preview is working fine.

This is my code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent {
                MyApp {
                SplashUI()
                }
            }
    }
    
     @Composable
        fun SplashUI() {
            Image(painterResource(R.drawable.logo_voodlee),"content description")
        }
    
        @Composable
        fun MyApp(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
         MaterialTheme {
                Surface(color = Color.Yellow) {
                    content()
                }
    
        }
}
    
       @Preview("MyScreen preview")
    @Composable
    fun DefaultPreview() {
            MyApp {
                SplashUI()
            }
        }
```

Been stuck at this for hours.
Please help me fix this!!!

Comment: "I get this error" -- where specifically do you get this error?

Comment: Which version of compose are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, I'm using 1.0.0-beta03

Comment: @CommonsWare, in build  output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I had imported the wrong `setContent`, and had  missed adding the dependency `"androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha05"`
Added it, and then imported the right `setContent`, i.e `androidx.activity.compose.setContent` - this solved the issue.