# Issue with LocalContext.current (@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently developing the Home Screen for my app but I've run into an issue. The line `val context = LocalContext.current` is causing an error that states, "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function". Could you provide any guidance on how to resolve this? To give you a better understanding, here's the complete function:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController) {
    // Use a Box to allow for layering of composables on top of each other
    // Used to keep the content at the bottom center of the screen.
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp), // Apply padding around the box
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter // Align content to the bottom center
    ) {
        // Column to stack buttons vertically
        Column(
            // Center column contents horizontally
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            // Space between the column contents
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            // Button to NAVIGATE TO THE BENEFITS SCREEN
            Button(
                onClick = { navController.navigate("sleep_benefits") },
                // Apply padding to only the top of the first button to push it upwards
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 1.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Learn About Sleep Benefits")
            }
            // Button for USER LOGIN
            Button(
                onClick = { /* TODO: Add navigation to login screen here */ }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Login to Track Sleep")
            }

            // New Sign Up Button
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    context.startActivity(Intent(context, SignInActivity::class.java))
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Sign Up")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried looking at this: [Error: "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801346/error-composable-invocations-can-only-happen-from-the-context-of-a-composabl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```kotlin
            // New Sign Up Button
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    context.startActivity(Intent(context, SignInActivity::class.java))
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Sign Up")
            }
```

with:

```kotlin
            val context = LocalContext.current

            // New Sign Up Button
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    context.startActivity(Intent(context, SignInActivity::class.java))
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Sign Up")
            }
```